# Watin - Submit button remain disabled after filling form

Tags: javascript, .net, web, watin

I have a website which I need to login to automatically.
I am trying to use Watin .NET library in order to do that.
When I fill out the user name and password fields using Watin, the sumbit button remains disabled.
I tried applying many events on the other fields (KeyPress, KeyDown, KeyUp, Tab, Enter...) Nothing worked.
Pardon me for finding the button by value, but this is the only way that I found that worked.

```
 var field = ie.TextField(Find.ByName("userName"));
 field.TypeText("username");
 field.KeyDown();
 field.KeyUp();            

 field = ie.TextField(Find.ByName("password"));
 field.TypeText("pwd");
 field.KeyDown();
 field.KeyUp();

 ie.Button(Find.ByValue("התחבר")).Click();
```

I am getting an exception that the button is disabled.
The page which I need to login to is:
https://portal.dorad.co.il/#/Login
All that I want is to find an automatic way to make the sumbit button enabled so that I can login.

Login Form Code:

```
<form class="span5 offset4 loginForm ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required" name="loginForm" ng-submit="doLogin()" autocomplete="off">
    <h2>
       Login
    </h2>
    <fieldset>
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="fullName">
               User Name
            </label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input name="userName" id="useName" ng-required="true" type="text" ng-model="user.userName" auto-fill-sync="" autocomplete="off" class="ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required" required="required">
                <span class="alert alert-error" ng-show="loginForm.userName.$error.required &amp;&amp; loginForm.userName.$dirty" style="display: none;">
                    Mandatory Field
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="emailAddress">
               Password
            </label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input name="password" id="password" type="password" ng-model="user.password" auto-fill-sync="" ng-required="true" autocomplete="off" class="ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required" required="required">
                <span class="alert alert-error" ng-show="loginForm.password.$error.required &amp;&amp; loginForm.password.$dirty" style="display: none;">
                    Mandatory Field
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <input type="submit" class="btn" value="התחבר" ng-disabled="loginForm.$invalid" disabled="disabled">
</form>
```

Comment: Did you check, if it has a change event for user name and password. If so, after entering the user name password, then trigger change event.
Also, is it possibile to post the html content, as I am unable to view the link that you have posted.

Comment: when I click on the page "view source" I don't see the username/password fields, but when I click on a field and then "Inspect Element" I can find the fields, so I don't understand where are they hiding...

Comment: see the form which I pasted above

Comment: There is no issue with the HTML. It seems to me that there are some java script validations that happens after entering the text in the text fields. If the data is proper in both the fields, then the Submit button would get enabled. So I guess the data entered might not be proper.

Comment: that is not true, I have the right data, but I also tried entering even a single character manually on each field - and the button became enabled. But when Watin inserts the content automatically some javascript event is not being fired. I am just unable to see which event it is!

Answer (score 1):

This might be due to firing of an event getting blocked.
Try using:

```
Element fg = ie.TextField(Find.ByName("password"));
fg.DomContainer.RunScript("$('#"+fg.id+'").change();");
```

This solved a similar problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Then try to use Eval function which takes java script code. Pass the two elements to the below method and check.

```
    private void ChangeAndBlur(Element element)
    {
        try
        {
            element.DomContainer.Eval(string.Format("$('#{0}').change()", element.Id));
            element.DomContainer.Eval(string.Format("$('#{0}').blur()", element.Id));
        }
        catch
        { }
     }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried it, but it didn't help.