# WatiN submit button is hidden(disabled)

Tags: javascript, c#, html, webbrowser-control, watin

I have to select an option in the `SelectList`, and then press a button, I thought to do it with WatiN in C#, but if you have another suggestion I would love to hear. 
When I select an item from the `SelectList` through the browser, everything works as it should :

[working from the browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/72JBv.png)

But when I try to do it through the code in C #, I'm able to select the item in the `SelectList` but the submit button does not appear:

[not working from the C# code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qF6l9.png)

The site's source (when item is not selected):

```html
<form ng-submit="rob()" class="ng-valid ng-dirty">
<select style="max-width: 235px" ng-model="robbery" ng-options="robbery.long_name for robbery in robberies track by robbery.id" class="ng-valid ng-touched ng-dirty"><option value="" class="">[Choose...]</option><option value="1" label="Shoplift - 5% D: 3 SP: 100%">Shoplift - 5% D: 3 SP: 100%</option><option value="2" label="Old lady - 10% D: 10 SP: 100%">Old lady - 10% D: 10 SP: 100%</option><option value="3" label="Car break-in - 10% D: 20 SP: 100%">Car break-in - 10% D: 20 SP: 100%</option><option value="4" label="Taxi - 10% D: 50 SP: 100%">Taxi - 10% D: 50 SP: 100%</option><option value="6" label="House - 10% D: 100 SP: 100%">House - 10% D: 100 SP: 100%</option><option value="7" label="Gas station - 10% D: 200 SP: 100%">Gas station - 10% D: 200 SP: 100%</option><option value="8" label="Grocery store - 10% D: 400 SP: 100%">Grocery store - 10% D: 400 SP: 100%</option><option value="10" label="Kidnapping - 15% D: 800 SP: 100%">Kidnapping - 15% D: 800 SP: 100%</option><option value="11" label="Jewellery - 15% D: 1500 SP: 100%">Jewellery - 15% D: 1500 SP: 100%</option><option value="12" label="Little City Bank - 15% D: 3000 SP: 100%">Little City Bank - 15% D: 3000 SP: 100%</option><option value="14" label="Car Saloon - 15% D: 4000 SP: 100%">Car Saloon - 15% D: 4000 SP: 100%</option><option value="16" label="Local bastards - 25% D: 6000 SP: 100%">Local bastards - 25% D: 6000 SP: 100%</option><option value="26" label="Safety deposit - 25% D: 8000 SP: 100%">Safety deposit - 25% D: 8000 SP: 100%</option><option value="19" selected="selected" label="Rave party - 25% D: 10000 SP: 100%">Rave party - 25% D: 10000 SP: 100%</option></select><br>
<!-- ngIf: robbery.id -->
</form>
```

The site's source (when item is selected):

```html
<form ng-submit="rob()" class="ng-valid ng-dirty ng-valid-parse">
<select style="max-width: 235px" ng-model="robbery" ng-options="robbery.long_name for robbery in robberies track by robbery.id" class="ng-valid ng-touched ng-dirty ng-valid-parse"><option value="" class="">[Choose...]</option><option value="1" label="Shoplift - 5% D: 3 SP: 100%">Shoplift - 5% D: 3 SP: 100%</option><option value="2" label="Old lady - 10% D: 10 SP: 100%">Old lady - 10% D: 10 SP: 100%</option><option value="3" label="Car break-in - 10% D: 20 SP: 100%">Car break-in - 10% D: 20 SP: 100%</option><option value="4" label="Taxi - 10% D: 50 SP: 100%">Taxi - 10% D: 50 SP: 100%</option><option value="6" label="House - 10% D: 100 SP: 100%">House - 10% D: 100 SP: 100%</option><option value="7" label="Gas station - 10% D: 200 SP: 100%">Gas station - 10% D: 200 SP: 100%</option><option value="8" label="Grocery store - 10% D: 400 SP: 100%">Grocery store - 10% D: 400 SP: 100%</option><option value="10" label="Kidnapping - 15% D: 800 SP: 100%">Kidnapping - 15% D: 800 SP: 100%</option><option value="11" label="Jewellery - 15% D: 1500 SP: 100%">Jewellery - 15% D: 1500 SP: 100%</option><option value="12" label="Little City Bank - 15% D: 3000 SP: 100%">Little City Bank - 15% D: 3000 SP: 100%</option><option value="14" label="Car Saloon - 15% D: 4000 SP: 100%">Car Saloon - 15% D: 4000 SP: 100%</option><option value="16" label="Local bastards - 25% D: 6000 SP: 100%">Local bastards - 25% D: 6000 SP: 100%</option><option value="26" label="Safety deposit - 25% D: 8000 SP: 100%">Safety deposit - 25% D: 8000 SP: 100%</option><option value="19" selected="selected" label="Rave party - 25% D: 10000 SP: 100%">Rave party - 25% D: 10000 SP: 100%</option></select><br>
<!-- ngIf: robbery.id --><input type="submit" ng-if="robbery.id" tabindex="-1" value="Rob the bastard!" class="btn btn-small btn-inverse ng-scope" click-once=""><!-- end ngIf: robbery.id -->
</form>
```

This is my C # code:

```
_browser.GoTo(gameURL);

WatiN.Core.Form form = _browser.Forms[1];
WatiN.Core.SelectList selectList = form.SelectLists[0];

selectList.Select(selectList.Options[selectList.Options.Count - 2].Text);
```

I tried everything they say in here: [Watin - Submit button remain disabled after filling form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25037819/watin-submit-button-remain-disabled-after-filling-form)

Comment: Any chance you can share the exact page? I want to take a look at it. Nothing seems to be really out of the ordinary so your code "should" work but is obvious that there's something missing.

Comment: Sure, it's in 'www.thecrims.com' Note: no 'http://' before the URL. Then you connect, you can do it with My Account: username - 'nhrnhr0' ; password - '6464f8' then click on robbery or insert the URL 'www.thecrims.com/robbery'. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: I've tried to get to the selectList but for some reason the state of the Browser is always "loading" (even when as a user you see it fine) so I don't have a chance to get to the List. Sorry, I've tried.

Comment: I also have this problem, after you entered the URL and press ENTER, delete the http:// from the URL line and it should work ...

Comment: If you do that manually the script gets disconnected from the program.

Comment: My bad. Replace 'https://' with 'http://' and it should work